# success: function AJAX não funciona

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho essa função em JQUERY e AJAX, ela executa o que eu quero, porém, não entre no sucess para exibir a msg de sucesso e resetar o form, ele tá enviando a imagem pro servidor e os dados do form, o unico problema é esse, não da retorno de sucesso.

```
$("#form-fichaanimal").submit(function(){

    var formulario = document.getElementById('form-fichaanimal');
    var formData = new FormData(formulario);

    $.ajax({
        url  : 'code-source/insert/ins-fichaanimal.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response){                      
            if(response.codigo == "1"){ 
                $("#btn-cadastrar-fichaanimal").html('Cadastrar');
                $("#mensagem").html(response.mensagem);
                $("#mensagem").addClass("alert alert-success");
                $("#altura").val("");
                $("#peso").val("");
                $("#sanidade").val("");
                $("#nutricao").val("");
                $("#data_ficha").val("");
                $("#modalidade").val("");
                $("#arquivo").val("");
                $("#cpf-proprietario-animal").val("");
                $("#nome").val("");
                $("#animal").val("");
            }

            else{           
                $("#btn-cadastrar-fichaanimal").html('Cadastrar');
                $("#mensagem").html("<strong>Erro: </strong>" + response.mensagem);
                $("#mensagem").addClass("alert alert-danger");
            }
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900);
    event.stopPropagation();

    setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#mensagem').html("");
    $('#mensagem').removeClass();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Meu código de retorno na classe PHP

```
$retorno = array('codigo' => 1, 'mensagem' => 'Cadastro realizado!');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Comment: antes de retornar, setou o header da resposta para indicar que é um json? assim por exemplo: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` confirme isso

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente seu problema está na linha que define o tipo de retorno esperado:

`{dataType:"json"}`

Porem o que voce mencionou que seu backend entrega não é um "json".

Apague a linha dataType. Ou mude para "string", pois os retornos esperados são: 
(xml, json, script, or html)

fonte da informação: [jquery dataType](http://Conforme%20[inserir%20a%20descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20do%20link%20aqui][1])

Comment: Responde sim, o dataType que ele definiu no Ajax é pra um retorno JSON, mas a composição do retorno que ele estruturou no backend não é um JSON... Obrigado, De nada

Comment: Ta melhor? Sou novo aqui, só estou tentando ajudar...

Comment: Melhorou um pouquinho. Não sou quem pego no pé, é sistema que avalia cada resposta e encaminha para uma fila de análise.  toda vez que uma mensagem  tem o link [Da Revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/234401) pode ter certeza que ela é oriunda de fila de análise.

Comment: O que eu poderia fazer para melhorar?

Comment: Exatamente isso que você está fazendo. Refinando o conteúdo e lastrando as informações em links de documentação confiável.

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar, mas eu consegui adicionando o evento beforeSend: function(){} antes do sucess